# Accessing POST parameters from web form using Request and not $_POST Symfony 3

Tags: php, html, forms, post, symfony

I have a web form that submits some hidden input fields with post parameters and I want to use Request object from Symfony.

This is how I'm doing it now using an API based request also with Postman app I can access the son values like this.

```
myAction(Request $request){

    $content = $request->getContent();

    $params = json_decode($content, true);

    $value = $params['value']; 
}
```

But when i use a web form it doesn't get the values this way. I was trying to figure out how to get the values and i ended up using the post variable which works fine.

```
$value = $_POST['value'];
```

I don't want to use the global variable but rather grab the value from the request. I don't have a super good reason why, other than I prefer it the `Request` way. Any help would be appreciated.

Is there something special I'd have to do with the HTML form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `$value = $request->request->get('value');` to get a single POST value.

Use `$values = $request->request->all()` to get all POST values.

From [symfony docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/controller.html#the-request-and-response-object)

Comment: Thanks Andy this works but it's not quite what i was looking for. i'd like to be able to access the request one time and save the entire json body in one variable. But i'd probably have to use AJAX or something to format it and give it a name but i won't worry about it too much it works which is good just a small pet peeve i guess :)

Comment: Sorry, then you should be able to get all of the values by using `$values = $request->request->all()`